# Quest DB FILL without aggregation

Tags: sample, questdb

Is there a way in QuestDB to use `FILL` without `SAMPLE BY`.

I have seen the coalesce function, but coalesce doesn't have the `PREV` option, to use the last value which was not a null value. The use case:

- every row has a timestamp in microsecond,
- I have a column witch has a value every microsecond,
- I have other columns at the same timestamp with a value only every 5 minutes.

So i would like to use the previous known value to replace `null` for the column with a value every 5 min, please?

I read the doc on QuestDb about `coalesce`, sample by and `FILL`, but can't find the option without aggregation:

Comment: [https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/fill/][1]
[https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/sample-by/#syntax][2]
[https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/conditional/#coalesce][3]

  [1]: https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/fill/
  [2]: https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/sample-by/#syntax
  [3]: https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/conditional/#coalesce

Comment: You'd normally do it with LAG function in SQL but QuestDb does not have window functions yet